# How to change post template

Tags: templates

I have a post featuring a product that I've created using advanced custom fields. I would like to have a link on the post that opens in a new window and displays the same product, just with a different look and info. (Note: I'm specifically looking to use a second template and not a different CSS because different info will be displayed on each template.) I've tried using the code below, but my custom template just returns a blank page. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Here's the link I'm using on the original template.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?custom-template=1">Link</a>
```

Here's the code that I'm putting at the top of the custom template.

```
if ($_GET['custom-template'] == 1) { include custom-template.php; return; }
```

Thanks, John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it you have two options here:

1. Pass the id to a [custom template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) and then create a custom `wp_query` loop and use `$_GET['id']` as the id of the loop.

For Example:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Pop Up View
*/
//get id from your url 
$id=$_GET['id'];

//start custom loop

$query = new WP_Query( 'p=$id' );
//loop stuff and page template here
?>
```

then you would call `<a href="custom-item-template?id=<?php the_ID();?>">Link</a>`

Or going more with your current code you could do something like

```
    if ($_GET['custom-template'] == 1) { 
       get_template_part( 'custom-template');
      die(); //or exit(); 
}
```

This fixed a few problems I see with your current code. One being that return can't be used outside of functions. Also uses [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) instead of include with is a more WordPress way to do it.

Both ways should work, hopefully that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks so much. I went with the second option and it works perfectly.